# ALT keys on laptop "fall asleep"

Tags: windows, laptop, keyboard, asus-laptop, windows-10-v1709

Basically, both my alt keys "fall asleep".  They will completely stop working.  Over time, and with the help of keyboardtester.com, I have learned that if I mash one of them about 15 times it will "wake up" both of them and they start working again.  It will work for a couple minutes or an hour.  Without fail though, they will both stop working again.  Wash, rinse, repeat.

I have also reset Windows and the issue persisted.

What on earth could be causing this?

ASUS Strix (GL502VY).  Bios version 202. 
Windows 10 1709 (16299.192)

Comment: It's worth noting that I was a PC Tech in a large hospital for many, many years and I never saw *anything* like this.  The keys "falling asleep" is the best description I can give.  It's just like when my Shield TV remote goes to sleep. I have to push the button a few times before it wakes up.

Comment: Does this occur with an external USB keyboard?

Comment: Can you test with another OS? Like some Linux live CD/DVD/USB. Do the keys "fall asleep" as well?

Comment: It does not happen with an external keyboard.  I have never spilled anything on it. I will try to test another OS.

Comment: @ScottBeeson Try to see with a program or a script that is able to [read the key pressed](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001577.htm).  It is possible that there is a [mechanical failure](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000305.htm), or better _it is starting a failure_. BTW you are sure that you did not spill anything. Good. ...but can you be sure that nobody else did? `:->`. If you suspect it is a driver/settings problem, try another live OS in order to understand it. Let us know...(and good luck)

Comment: have you tried taking them off the keyboard and seeing if the connector is sticky or has something in it etc.?

Comment: I haven't tried taking them off since both alt keys have the same issue.  I don't believe it's a hardware problem. However, I'm willing to try anything.  Should they just pop off? I've never removed keys from a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

1. If "normally pressing" about 15 times one of them wakes up "both" Alt keys that would rule out faulty buttons.
2. If "mashing" about 15 times one of them wakes up "that" Alt key only it would indicate a faulty button.
3. If "mashing" about 15 times one of them wakes up "both" Alt keys it sounds "contradictory" and probably this is the result of a wrong conclusion.

Alt keys are not used very often plus if the keyboard i.e. suffered some kind of spill, or it is used in a very humid environment it might lead to erratic buttons that can become temporary alive if they are mashed several times.

It might happened that you alternatively mashed both buttons and it looked like after mashing only one it releases both keys; I think this would be a wrong inference.

Edit:

If there is not a hardware problem something (probably a virus)
might be remapping your keyboard.
read about remapping here.
[Can I switch the alt and ctrl keys on my keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/1190329/can-i-switch-the-alt-and-ctrl-keys-on-my-keyboard)

Can you just add an USB keyboard and see if you get the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try installing new drivers.

If this fails it is probably a hardware fault (e.g. the keyboard itself) You could try keyboard cleaning products / switch cleaner.

If that doesn't work then the keyboard will need replaced and if a new keyboard doesn't fix it it may be a motherboard problem.

But honestly, the best thing you can do is take it to a computer repair shop. There, they can take it apart, diagnose it, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a **damaged ribbon cable** which connects the keyboard to the motherboard.
Remove the keyboard from the laptop, you'll see a ribbon cable - usually folded like a 'V' - and try to fold it carefully the oher way and then assemble your laptop.

If that fails, there might be another option.

Shut down your laptop, unplug **every** cable, then romove the battery. Hold the power button for like 60s, then replace the battery and the cables. Now you can power on your laptop.